# Hibernate doesn't map column name in entity as per default naming scheme

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

As per my knowledge, Hibernate (or Spring maybe) should map *camel case* to *snake case* (with underscores) by default.

But it doesn't work here.

#### My Entity snippet

```
@Entity(name = "asset_version_dependency")
public class AssetVersionDependency {
   
    @Column(name = "optional_ind")
    private Boolean optionalInd;
}
```

#### Issue

If I remove `name` then I will get following error:

> Invalid column name 'optionalInd'

Hibernate doesn't map column name in the entity as per default naming scheme.

#### My properties

In Spring's `application.properties` I am not using anything special:

```
sai.datasource.jdbcUrl=(someting)
sai.datasource.username=(someting)
sai.datasource.password=(someting)
sai.datasource.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
sai.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
sai.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
server.port=8081
```

#### Entity manager

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "saiEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "saiTransactionManager")
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sai.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariDataSource ds = (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        ds.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean("saiEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean productEntityManager() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());

        em.setPackagesToScan("com.example.persistence.entity");
        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean("jpaPropertyMap")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sai.datasource.jpa")
    @NonNull
    public Map<String, String> properties() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Bean("saiTransactionManager")
    @Primary
    @NonNull
    public PlatformTransactionManager saiTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("saiEntityManager") @NonNull EntityManagerFactory saiEntityManager) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(saiEntityManager);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the column name that generate for `optionalInd` with `@Column(name = "optional_ind")` ?

Comment: @DevThiman It will generate `optional_ind`